# Is there a version of "the past year" without article "the", as in the case of "last year" and "the last year"?

Tags: grammar, meaning, articles, grammaticality, idiomatic-language

There are both **"the last year"** and **"last year"** (without **"THE"**) , and they both exist and they have different meanings.

**Last year** (the previous calender year)

**The last year** (the last 12 months)

However, I wonder does the same situation exist when it comes to **"THE past year"?** or does it only have one version which is **the past year**? I mean is there a **"past year"** (without the?)

**the past year** (the last 12 months before now)

What about **past year ?** Is there something like past year?

Comment: You can have **a** past year but not **a** last year(for this meaning of last), so last and past are different in this way too.

Comment: A chart or table of the months of the year is a **calendar**. A **calender** is a machine used to press (cloth, rubber, paper, etc.) between rollers or plates in order to smooth and glaze or to thin into sheets.

Comment: No, you can't use ***past year*** without a determiner (normally ***the***, but you can certainly say *I haven't had a holiday **this past year***). But ***the past year*** and ***the last year*** are often equivalent and interchangeable (not in contexts like *The / My / His last year at school was miserable*, though).

Comment: If past years are any guide, the sun may shine here occasionally between May and September.

Comment: Occasionally used: *yesteryear*, https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yesteryear However, it can also mean a generalized time in the past.